# edit object/arrayList in java again and again

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have sorted AllayList with Objects refer to my previous post [How to sort and get highest value from Java Object/ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026343/how-to-sort-and-get-highest-value-from-java-object-)

```
ArrayList<> allStudents = new ArrayList();
allStudents.add(new Student("H", 99, 93) );    
allStudents.add(new Student("C", 98, 92) );
allStudents.add(new Student("B", 98, 91) );    
allStudents.add(new Student("A", 80, 94) );
allStudents.add(new Student("F", 70, 84) );
```

Now in
step1: I want to fetch anyone (randomly select any object) of them else the first highest(that is "H"), then edit numbers then save it back.
step2: I want to to fetch anyone (randomly select any object) of them else the second highest(that is "C"), then edit numbers then save it back.
step3:I want to to fetch anyone (randomly select any object) of them else the third highest(that is "B"), then edit numbers then save it back.

When all 5 will be finished, then the process will start again from step1. In this way I can reduce all student's numbers.

If someone please suggest me how can I do that?

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile -- you have the diamond operator on the wrong side, and the constructor is for a raw type.

Comment: what have you tried? Get a random number from 0-3, do some simple arithmetic, that's it

Comment: I have tried the below one but of course you are right. I used simple math. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer bu doing some simple arithmetic. Create another class to select random number for bellow cases:

step1: Taking current student index
step2: Randomly selecting one student, whom number should reduce, rather than step1 student

continuing again step1 and step2